# How do I use the override keyword for multiple generic inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance

I have a generic IDetachable interface, which provides one method:

```
template<class T>
class IDetachable {
public:
  virtual T detached() const = 0;
};
```

I have these example classes:

```
class A: public IDetachable<A> {
  virtual A detached() const override {
    // some implementation which returns a detached A object
  }
};
```

The problem occurs when inheriting B:

```
class B: public A, public IDetachable<B> {
  virtual B detached() const override {
    // some implementation which returns a detached B object
  }
};
```

clang++ tells me:

```
error: virtual function 'detached' has a different return type ('B')
  than the function it overrides (which has return type 'A')
```

To me it seems, that the compiler automatically chose the first parent for the override keyword. Is there any chance to tell the compiler which parent's method I intended to inherit with the override keyword?

Comment: That's the point of `override` - it will cause an error if the signature of the function in the derived class is not exactly the same as the one in the base class.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I believe the point is that he wants it to override the `detached` in `IDetachable<B>` rather than `A`.

Comment: The first base class is not special in any way whatsoever. A virtual function must correctly override all parents. If that's not possible, you just cannot override at all.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The signature does match the one in one of the base classes. The problem is that it's trying to override two conflicting functions, which is an error with or without `override`.

Comment: As answered by @AdrianMay, you cannot overload two different functions with the same name uniquely on their return values; their list of parameters must also be different. To be clear, you cannot have both `A detachable()` and `B detachable()` because the only distinction between these two is their return values; however, you can have `A detachable(A*)` and `B detachable(B*)`.

Comment: Could a `using IDetachable<B>::detached()` help in this context?

Comment: Btw if you pass polymorphic objects around by value you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Is your intention that class `B` should have two `detached()` functions—one returning an `A`, one returning a `B`—or should it just have one such function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a dummy T to detach:

```
template<class T>
class IDetachable {
public:
  virtual T detached(T*dummy) const = 0;
};
```

You ignore that parameter but now you can specialise on it.

Comment: The function call is ambiguous if is called without parameters (due to the default parameter value).

Comment: So, in order to avoid errors, I would suggest to get rid of the default parameter, you'll need a parameter anyway to disambiguate the function, don't you?

Comment: @AdrianMay Either you call it using detach((A*)null), or - what I will use in my code - you pass it as IDetachable<A>& into a method which calls the method.

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't about how to override one or the other its the fact that you can't have two functions with the same signature and different return types.

**Consider:**

```
template<class T, class U>
class IDetachable {
public:
    virtual ~IDetachable() {}
    virtual T detached() const = 0;
    virtual U detached() const = 0; // whoopse problem
};
```

It doesn't matter how you end up with two same-signature functions returning different types its always illegal.

@AdrianMay provides a working answer. He changes the signatures of the functions.

Comment: You can inherit such functions from different bases though.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not really sure how? If I put the same function with different return types in separate base classes and inherit from each of them I still get the same error. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @n.m. is your example even the same as the OP? you're not using templates nor pure virtual functions!

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Templates are orthogonal to the issue. If one of the conflicting functions is pure virtual, your class can never be instantiated, because you cannot override.

Comment: @Galik This is a good explanation of the problem.  I guess the solution of Adrian May is quite usable.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want return type covariance? It works only on pointers and references:

```
template<class T>
class IDetachable {
public:
    virtual T* detached() const = 0;
};


class A: public IDetachable<A> {
    virtual A* detached() const override {
        // some implementation which returns a detached A object
    }
};

class B: public A, public IDetachable<B> {
    virtual B* detached() const override {
        // some implementation which returns a detached B object
    }
};

int main() {
    IDetachable<A> *da = new A;
    A *a = da->detached();
    IDetachable<B> *db = new B;
    B *b = db->detached();
}
```

Comment: [Runnable sample code here](https://ideone.com/A6fLNo). (So you can see that calling detached does what you want for each IDetachable ptr.